# Redirection based on URL?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

How to do 301 Htaccess  redirect ?

Just Moved Site A Whole content to Site B . This site has 3000 plus url so cann't redirect by specifying each and every link . change is only domain name . if some clicks on sitea.com/whateverispage then he/she should redirect  to siteb.com/whateverispage

```
www.sitea.com/productinfo -->www.siteb.info/productinfo
```

any idea to how yo get this result , this is somehow similar to wildcard in SQl and PHP

Answer (score 0):

please try this

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sitea.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.sitea.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://siteb.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

hope it will work for you